# How to return back to selected row of ListBox

Tags: vb.net

I built a listBox that contains 5 rows.with pressing ENTER key on each of them a new ListBox generates and ESC key goes back to previous one.
Problem is: When I ENTER 3rd row of first ListBox,after pressing ESC it goes back but first row actives.How can i active last selectes row?(in my example i want that 3rd row be selected after pressing esc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the listBox1.SelectedIndex to get and set the selected row:

```
Dim index As Integer = listBox1.SelectedIndex
listBox1.SelectedIndex = index + 1
```

Comment: Sorry but I didnt understand your algorithm.would you please explain!

Comment: Sorry the delay, it's simple, it get the selectedIndex of your listBox(the selected Row), then it just set the index + 1 to select the row below. No secret.